# Tutorial on git using git bash fixing the conflict

Tags: git, bash, merge

I've following a tutorial on git using git bash and came to the point where after typing the git command `git commit` below show up. I'm in windows operating system and I can no longer proceed.

```
Merge branch 'second-branch'

# Conflicts:
#       index.txt
#
# It looks like you may be committing a merge.
# If this is not correct, please remove the file
#       .git/MERGE_HEAD
# and try again.


# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   index.txt
~
~
~
~
```

anyone can suggest what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close the editor?

since this editor is [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), which has a *modal* user interface, it might be a bit unusual if you are used to typical w32 programs...

Here's how you save the file and close it:

1. press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go into command-mode
2. type (this will appear in the footer-line of the screen) `:wq` (colon and then type wq) and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> (this will **w**rite the file and **q**uit the editor)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that it was called vi, that's my first option actually, but I've been thinking maybe there's a proper of way of handling it. Anyways thanks